# Calling a function at certain positions in "for", "if" loops

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a JS function that will loop through elements in my HTML document and perform a function on those that have a certain attribute value (a particular URL as the value of `@href`). However, I am having trouble passing the right element to the function.

Here is a typical HTML element:

```
<a id="xyz" n="1" href="www.example.com">text</a>
```

The document consists of many of these. Each `@id` is unique to its `<a>` element. Multiple `@href` URLS are involved. These do not necessarily correspond to the `@n` attribute value. So it looks something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>MyDocument</title>
</head>
<body>
<a id="abc" n="1" href="www.example.com" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">text</a>
<a id="def" n="2" href="www.anotherexample.com" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">text</a>
<a id="xyz" n="1" href="www.example.com" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">text</a>
<a id="ghi" n="1" href="www.anotherexample.com" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">text</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I am only interested in those with an `@n` attribute.

Here is my JS function. This is meant to pass all elements from the document with the same `@href` URL to `myOtherFunction`.

```
function myFunction(id){
var el = document.getElementById(id);
var url= el.attributes[2].value;
var els = document.querySelectorAll("a[n]");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    if(els[i].attributes[2].value = url) {
        myOtherFunction(els[i].id);
    }
}
}
```

However, it only ever passes the first `<a>` element in the document, even when that does not have the `@href` value from `el`.

So, imagine that `<a>` element `@id` "def" has been clicked on.

**Expected Result**
`<a>` elements `@id` "def" and `@id` "ghi" get passed to `myOtherFunction`.

**Current Result**
`<a>` element `@id` "abc" gets passed to 'myOtherFunction'.

The `i` variable in the call of `myOtherFunction` is presumably not retaining its value from the "if" condition. How would I make it do so?

Or am I on completely on the wrong track for what I am trying to do?

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve] with relevant HTML

Comment: `=` is assignment. You want `==` to compare.

Comment: And what is `el.attributes[2].value;` ? If el is an input field, select or textarea, then it is el.value, if not, then there is no value

Comment: Hardcoding an attribute index, oof...

Comment: Even better with three equals ===

Comment: Thanks. I have now provided a full model of the HTML document, with details of where `el` comes from. When the `<a>` element is clicked, its `@id` is passed to `myFunction` and that is used to retrieve it as `el`.

I will now go and play with `=` ...

Comment: Thanks @TiiJ7. You are right. I don't know what I was thinking using just "=".

Answer (score 2):

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>a</title>
</head>

<body>
    
    <a id="xyz" n="1" href="www.example.com">text</a>

    <script>

        function myFunction(id) {
            var el = document.getElementById(id);
            //var url = el.attributes[2].value;
            var url = el.getAttribute('href')
            debugger
            var els = document.querySelectorAll("a[n]");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
                if (els[i].getAttribute('href') == url) {
                    //myOtherFunction(els[i].id);
                }
            }
        }

        myFunction('xyz');
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. May I ask, why is `myOtherFunction(els[i].id);` commented out? Obviously, with no remaining code to be executed when the `if` condition is met, nothing happens.

Comment: If I adopt your solution and don't comment it out, it passes on the `<a>` element on which I have clicked but none of the others with the same URL. The point of the function is to pass on **all** the elements with the same `href` value (URL) as the clicked on element. Sorry if I haven't explained clearly.

Comment: Apologies. I just double checked. I don't necessarily get the element I clicked on. I get the first element in the document with the same URL. That is good progress :-) But I still need all the elements, not just the first one with the same URL. Thank you, nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement has an `=` which is an assignment and will thus override the value instead of comparing. You can use `===` (or `==`) to compare.

Also instead of using the attributes, you can access the `href` property directly.

```js
function myFunction(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    var url = el.href;
    var els = document.querySelectorAll("a[n]");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        if(els[i].href === url) {
            myOtherFunction(els[i].id);
        }
    }
}

function myOtherFunction(id) {
    console.log(id);
}
```

```html
<a id="abc" n="1" href="www.example.com" onclick="myFunction(this.id);return false">text</a>
<a id="def" n="2" href="www.anotherexample.com" onclick="myFunction(this.id);return false">text</a>
<a id="xyz" n="1" href="www.example.com" onclick="myFunction(this.id);return false">text</a>
<a id="ghi" n="1" href="www.anotherexample.com" onclick="myFunction(this.id);return false">text</a>
```

Note: `return false` was simply added to prevent the browser from following the link.

Answer (score 0):

#### A generic solution

The **advantage** here is that you can **search** for **any attribute**, you want and **output** **any attribute value**, you want.

```js
function El(selector) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
}

function addListeners(els, type, listener) {
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i += 1) {
    var el = els[i];
    el.addEventListener(type, listener);
  }
}

// Get 'r' values from attribute 'search'
function getValues(els, that, search, r) {
  var res = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i += 1) {
    var el = els[i];
    if (that.getAttribute(search) === el.getAttribute(search)) {
      res.push(el.getAttribute(r));
    }
  }
  return res;
}

function runOnEach(arr, fn) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    fn(arr[i]);
  }
}

// Create your own function
function f(val) {
  console.log(val);
}


function listener(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var arr = getValues(links, this, "href", "id");
  runOnEach(arr, f);
}

var links = El("a[n]");

addListeners(links, "click", listener);
```

```html
<a id="abc" n="1" href="www.example.com">text</a>
<a id="def" n="2" href="www.anotherexample.com">text</a>
<a id="xyz" n="1" href="www.example.com">text</a>
<a id="ghi" n="1" href="www.anotherexample.com">text</a>
```